# Error en regla unique en actualizar

Tags: laravel, validación, requests

Me encuentro testeando la funcionalidad de mi Request de validacion de datos y me encuentro con el siguiente problema.

Cuando quiero actualizar un registro no tengo problema, el problema lo tengo que le quiero asignar el mismo nombre que otro registro, en este caso deberia arrojar el error "el nombre ya se encuentra registrado" pero en vez de devolverme el error directamente el codigo explota.

Adjunto mis codigos a ver si alguien tiene nocion de que puede estar pasando.

Controlador

```
public function update(SucursalUpdate $request, $id)
{
    $sucursal = Sucursal::find($id);

    $sucursal->name = $request->name;
    $sucursal->estado = $request->estado;

    $sucursal->save();

    return redirect()->route('sucursales.index')->with('info','La sucursal fue actualizada correctamente');
}
```

Request SucursalUpdate

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'      =>  'required',
        Rule::unique('sucursals')->ignore($this->id),
    ];
}
```

Migracion Tabla Sucursals

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('sucursals', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');

        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->boolean('estado')->defalut(1);

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Archivo de rutas

```
{Route::resource('sucursales', 'Admin\SucursalController');
Route::get('sucursales/changeStatus/{id}', 'Admin\SucursalController@changeStatus')->name('sucursales.changeStatus');}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema era que me encontraba utulizando un controlador de resource por lo que las rutas que generan no siempre son /{id}

Al utilizar el comando

> php artisan route:list

Comprobe que la ruta que me generaba para el put era la siguiente

> sucursales/{sucursale}

Por lo que cambie mi archivo de reglas por lo siguiente

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'      =>  'required|unique:sucursals,name,'.$this->sucursale,
    ];
}
```

Y quedo andando a la perfección.

Answer (score 1):

Las reglas se escriben como un solo string separadas por `|` o separás por comas y encerrás todo entre corchetes ([documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic)).

Por otro lado, en vez de utilizar `$this->id` deberías chequear si existe una *sucursal*, que existirá solo si estás editando una, pero no creando.

```php
public function rules()
{
    $id = $this->route('sucursale')->id ?? null;

    return [
        'name' => ['required', Rule::unique('sucursals')->ignore($id)],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Si lo pongo asi tal cual me decis al editar un registro y no cambiar el nombre me tira que el nombre se encuentra duplicado

Comment: Ahí edité mi respuesta, si lo que querés pasar es el ID al `ignore`, primero hay que chequear si existe alguno.